# MinIO deactivate quota and acl for users

Tags: acl, minio, quota

I have MinIO on my dev architecture -> however, this infrastructure need to be very secure.

Questions :

- I do not want my users to be able to share data without the agreement of the admin -> is it possible ? (MinIO CLI)
- same for the anonymous URL
- Quota : since 2022-12-13, quota management move from mc admin to mc -> it's means that user can change their own quota ?